# get MSWord paragraph number via COM

Tags: python, com, ms-word

I process MSWord document with Python

```
for paragraph in MSWord.Documents[0].ListParagraphs:
    print(paragraph.ID+' '+paragraph.Range.Text.replace('\u206d','?')+'\n\n')
```

I Don't find how get MSWord paragraph number in API documentation
cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph_members

Any idea ?

Comment: NB. by paragraph number, I mean something like « 1.2.1 »

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=59) you can find a VBA macro that finds the paragraph number, you could call it via COM

Comment: Thanks Fábio for this tip, but I want to get a leveled number like 1.2.1 for the first third level paragraph under a 1.2 paragraph. Do you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
print paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListString
```